# jQuery to access DOM in a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to scrape various elements in a table from this [site](http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html) to teach myself scraping using node.js, cheerio and request

I have trouble getting the items in the table, essentially I want to get 'rank','company' and '3-year growth' from the table. How do I do this?

Based on an online [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping), I have developed my scraping.js script to look like this:

```
    var request = require ('request'),
        cheerio = require ('cheerio');     
    request('http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html', function (error, response, html) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        $('tr.ng-scope').each(function(i, element){ //problem probably lies here
          var a = $(this).get(0);
          console.log(a);
        });
      }
    });
```

However, I am sure I am not getting the line with comment above right. Is there a way I can access the attributes in the table better?

I notice the Xpaths are as such

//*[@id="col-r"]/table/tbody/tr[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)/td[1](http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html) -- rank

//*[@id="col-r"]/table/tbody/tr[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)/td[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)/a -- name of company

//*[@id="col-r"]/table/tbody/tr[2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)/td[3] -- 3 year growth rate

Just trying to figure out how to access these attributes accordingly..

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.

The `$().get()` method returns the element. In your case `var a` is the `TR`. That's not necessarily what you want.

What you need to do is further subdivide each row into the individual `TD`'s. I did this using `$(this).find('td')`. Then, I grab each `TD` 1 by 1 and extract the text out of it, converting that into an object where the key represents the field of the table. All of these are aggregated into an array, but you can use the basic concept to build whatever data structure you see fit to utilize.

```
    request('http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html', function (error, response, html) {
        if(error || response.statusCode != 200) return;

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var DATA = [];

        $('tr.ng-scope').each(function(){
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');

            DATA.push({
                rank:     $tds.eq(0).text(),
                company:  $tds.eq(1).text(),
                growth:   $tds.eq(2).text(),
                revenue:  $tds.eq(3).text(),
                industry: $tds.eq(4).text()
            });
        });

        console.log(DATA);
    });
```

Comment: thanks, when i run this code, i just get [] as output. using console.log(DATA.length), i get 0. Is there something I can correct? Ideally I want to display the attributes..

Comment: Sounds like the $('tr.ng-scope') selector isn't finding anything.

Comment: It may have something to do with the scope of my DATA variable. I updated the code to localize it to the callback. Give that a shot @stretchr.

Comment: i'm not sure if anything is being stored in the variables, tried doing console.log($tds.eq(0).text()); below var tds, nothing got printed in the console..

Comment: Do a `console.log( $('tr.ng-scope').length )`. Like I said before, it sounds like it's not even entering the each loop. If there's actually a length, THEN do `console.log( $tds.length )`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60596/discussion-between-stretchr-and-thethechad).