# Phantomjs to scrape webpage function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, phantomjs, scrape

I am using phantomjs to learn how to scrape a webpage, so far I have developed the following code below.. I know that I am able to connect to the site, but I am unable to get data from the table at all..am I on the right track?

My goal is to scrape data from the table on [this](http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html) site. I also understand that I need to use includeJs or injectJs to wait for the table to load else I would be scraping an empty html page. I am trying to put these concepts together, but am stuck for over 3 days now..please give some guidance..

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('Welcome to scraping...');

page.open('http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html', function(status) {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
      var DATA = [];
      var res= document.getElementById((this).find('td')).eq(0).text();
      console.log(res); //**See output below for what is happening here**
        $('tr.ng-scope').each(function(){
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');

            DATA.push({
                rank:     $tds.eq(0).text(),
                company:  $tds.eq(1).text(),
                growth:   $tds.eq(2).text(),
                revenue:  $tds.eq(3).text(),
                industry: $tds.eq(4).text()
            });
        });

        console.log(DATA); 
      console.log('Got into func');  
      //return document.getElementById('myagent').textContent;
    });
    console.log('Got out of function');
    console.log(ua);
  }
  phantom.exit();
  });
  
});
```

**The output I am getting is:**

> Welcome to scraping...
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
>
> http://stage.inc.com/js/Inc5000ListApp.js?UPDATE1:2
> http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html:2485
>
> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(this.find('td')).eq')
>
> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3     //what does this mean??
>
> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():20
>
> phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():20
>
> Got out of function
>
> null

Comment: weird. `page.open` chokes on the page because it tries to run a js on the page with an angular js dependency before it finishes loading angular js. this all happens before it even reaches the callback for `page.open` so I don't know how you would even fix that. FWIW, the page is gzipped, and I think phantomjs has issues with gzipped pages sometimes, idk if related but: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10930

Comment: this is interesting, so what's the best way to scrape such a page then? can the code above be improved to make it serve stretchr's purpose?

Comment: [cheers](https://github.com/fallanic/cheers) has an option to use a headless browser. Note that if this helps I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, can you please post it as an answer..

Comment: @user3995789, can you explain more about the cheers option? It does not work for me, tried running it on my pc and got errors that pointed me to line 27 of the code (cheers.scrape(config).then...and also line 71 of cheers.js, which is just a '});'...not too sure what's happening here??

Comment: @chiliNUT, are you sure the page is choking? I am able to retrieve some data such as title, and also can scrape the entire site after modifying the function in http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

So.. I am wondering I am down to constructing my object properly...have created a separate post for this..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706972/phantomjs-not-reaching-function

Comment: @stretchr turns out `headless browser` option is not yet implemented, so you have to wait for it. If you don't need it I will post it as an answer.

Comment: You can scrape fine because apparently the html is loading, which wouldnt necessarily be affected by scripts not loading, which is where the angular error is happening

Comment: struggling with how can i correct/work around this angular error..any idea?