# phantomjs not reaching function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom, phantomjs

following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696824/phantomjs-to-scrape-webpage-function-not-working?noredirect=1#comment40165949_25696824) , I have rewritten my script but am unable to reach the function where I am performing the scrape of data. As a result my object is null.

How can I ensure I reach the function?
How can I populate the object?
(note I the object and the way to populate it is based on discussion from [an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658217/jquery-to-access-dom-in-a-site/25658410?noredirect=1#comment40097230_25658410), but please let me know if I am making any error here in the script below)

Error Output:

> ReferenceError: cant find variable: angular (not sure what this
> means...am ignoring for now)
> http://stage.inc.com/js/Inc5000ListApp.js?UPDATE1:2
>
> http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html:2485
>
> Read About the Companies in
> the Inc. 5000 | Inc.com (this is the title, which am printing)
>
> null
> (the object is null and I don't know why??..well actually the function
> is not being accessed, but how I can correct this...)

**Code**

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://www.inc.com/inc5000/index.html', function(status) {

  var title = page.evaluate(function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
  }, 'title');

  console.log(title);
  page.injectJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js');
  var dataObj= page.evaluate(function() { 
    console.log('Reached scrapeData');
    var DATA = [];
        $('tr.ng-scope').each(function(){
            var $tds = $(this).find('td');
            DATA.push({
                rank:     $tds.eq(0).text(),
                company:  $tds.eq(1).text(),
                growth:   $tds.eq(2).text(),
                revenue:  $tds.eq(3).text(),
                industry: $tds.eq(4).text()
            });
        });

        console.log(DATA);
    });
    console.log(dataObj);
  phantom.exit();

});
```

Comment: wow, that's vry interesting. I am stuck on exactly the same issue

Comment: That's not how `injectJs` works. You need `includeJs` for remote files with a callback.

Comment: Don't you need to `return` from the `evaluate` callback?

Comment: how should i modify my script?